# Getting text? from full xpath quick question

Tags: python, xpath

Relatively new in programming, doing Python with Selenium and Xpath

this is from this website:https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NASDAQ/AMZN/earnings/

what I am trying to do is copy the dates of the past earnings.

Problem is it is in the table and it also has tag.

I have this full Xpath:

/html/body/div[1]/main/article/form/div[8]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]

and upon inspection it shows this

```
< td data-sort-value="20201027000000">10/27/2020 < / td >
```

I am trying to get the `10/27/2020` out from here but I don't know how to.

It is easy when it is just the `< td >$1.53< /td >` where just giving the full xpath and then doing a .text on it gives me the text.

point is how do I get `10/27/2020`. I would suspect that I would have to go over data-sort-value="" part.

Here is what I have :

```
stringeEPSxpath = """/html/body/div[1]/main/article/form/div[8]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr[""" + row + """]/td[1]"""

Date = stringeEPSxpath.text
```

(the row part is just me iterating the website page through a loop no problem there.)

For the rest of my code it has been pretty simple :

```
stringeEPSxpath = """/html/body/div[1]/main/article/form/div[8]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr[""" + row + """]/td[3]"""
    stringEPSxpath = """/html/body/div[1]/main/article/form/div[8]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr[""" + row + """]/td[4]"""

    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(stringeEPSxpath)
    elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(stringEPSxpath)

    fix1 = (elem.text).replace(')','')
    fix2 = (elem2.text).replace(')','')

    eps1 = fix1.replace('(','-')
    eps2 = fix2.replace('(','-')
```

As you can see above all I had to do was set a variable to it then use .text to convert it to a string. But now that does not work for dates.

The end result is the error of `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'` which I would suspect is because of the `data-sort-value="20201027000000"` part.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the url?

Comment: https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NASDAQ/PYPL/earnings/ not the same stock ( the other was AMZN) but exact same format

Comment: Wait never mind I found the reason, I forgot to write a line of code that would have it actually work. Thanks for the response it got me working on the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

In this code stringeEPSxpath is string, not WebElement.

```
stringeEPSxpath = """/html/body/div[1]/main/article/form/div[8]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr[""" + row + """]/td[1]"""

Date = stringeEPSxpath.text
```

You can try this one:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//td[@data-sort-value='20201027000000']")
Date = element.text
```

Comment: is there a way to iterate through your approach? Is there a way to sort through the data-sort-value part. Because that '20201027000000' part is something that I am trying to find.

Comment: never mind I forgot one line of code (driver.find_elementbyxppath) which actually makes the thing work thanks.

Comment: this code will check one element.

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//td[contains(@data-sort-value,'20201027000000')]")

You can find element list of td contains @data-sort-value with changing find_element to find_elements.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot driver.find_element_by_xpath(stringeEPSxpath)  which actually uses xpath. Since I copy and pasted from my other program I guess I deleted too much and completely forgot to add in the driver.findxpath.